# A strategy to create good initial guess for Lorentzian model fit

Tags: fitting, data, machine-learning

I was preparing an answer for a question that got deleted, so I will post this anyhow.

Given a set of data with a hump

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DMhcUZAQ","CSV"]
```

[image]

that one may want to fit to a Lorentzian model

```
model = a/((t - b)^2 + d) + c;
```

**How to create a good initial guess for all the fit parameters?**

That should include estimates for:

- Centre
- Width
- Peak value
- Baseline

or equivalent parameters.

Comment: Thank you for drafting this! I was also working on an alternative approach to the same question, and I was frustrated when it was deleted.

Comment: +1 on both question and answer.  Just curious:  Is this simulated data?  I ask because dividing all of the responses by 0.004 results in integers (which suggests either simulations or that the response consists of counts which might then suggest Poisson regression).

Comment: @JimB Not sure. The data comes from [this deleted question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/270696/27951). It was part of a series of similar questions from the same user, who at some point mentioned that it was related to high resolution laser spectroscopy. Passing familiarity with the field suggests that the raw measurements were indeed integer counts.

Answer (score 10):

## The initial guess

We load the data

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DMhcUZAQ","CSV"]
```

The guess components

```
centre = Total[Times@@@data]/Total[data[[All,2]]]; (* Centroid *)
{base,peak}= MinMax[data[[All,2]]];  (* Vertical range *)
{xmin,xmax}= MinMax[data[[All,1]]];  (* Horizontal range *)
width = (Power[data[[All,1]] - centre,2].data[[All,2]])/Total[data[[All,2]]] (* Width *)
```

The model

```
model = a/((t - b)^2 + d) + c;
```

the complete guess

```
fitguess = {{a, peak*width}, {b, centre}, {c, base}, {d, width}}
```

Let's see if it's any close

```
Show[
    ListPlot[
        data
        ,PlotStyle->Blue
        ,PlotTheme->"Scientific"
    ],
    Plot[
        Evaluate[model/.Rule@@@fitguess]
        ,{t,xmin,xmax}
        ,PlotStyle->Red
    ]
]
```

not too bad for an initial guess.

[image]

## The actual fit

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data
    , model
    , fitguess
    , t
];

Show[
    dataplot,
    Plot[
        Evaluate[fit[x]]
        ,{x,xmin,xmax}
    ]
]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using a model of the Lorentzian curve that more explicitly highlights the meaning of the parameters:

```
newmodel = area/Pi width/((t - peak)^2 + width^2);
```

In the model above, the position of the peak is indicated by `peak`, the curve's width parameter by `width`, and the area under the curve is given directly by `area`, as one can confirm below:

```
assumptions = {width > 0, peak ∈ Reals, area > 0};

(* Area under the curve *)
Integrate[newmodel, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> assumptions]
(* Out: area *)

(* Value at max *)
valueAtMax = Simplify[MaxValue[newmodel, t], Assumptions -> assumptions]
(* Out: area/(π width) *)

(* full width at half maximum = 2*width *)
Solve[newmodel == valueAtMax/2, t]
(* Out: {{t -> peak - width}, {t -> peak + width}} *)
```

With this model, fitting is easier as well:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/DMhcUZAQ", "CSV"];
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, newmodel, {width, peak, area}, t];
result["BestFitParameters"]
(* Out: {width -> 198.68, peak -> 4959.41, area -> 215.959} *)

Show[
  ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[result[t], {t, 4370, 5600}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
]
```

[image: comparison of data and fit]

The only caveat is the fact that the area and width parameters are somewhat correlated:

```
TableForm[
  result["CorrelationMatrix"],
  TableHeadings -> {{"width", "peak", "area"}, {"width", "peak", "area"}}
]
```

[image: correlation table between parameters]

With this, one would be in a better position to optimize the starting values of the parameters thanks to a more immediate grasp of their physical meaning.